# User authentication PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

First of all. I'm new to both PHP/SQL and StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if my post is weird. I'm having a hard time figuring out what is wrong with my code. I have registered several users (each with a password ofc), but i only get login failed. Is it my if that is wrong?

Thank you.

```php
<?php

session_start();

    //Connecting and choosing DB
    $connection = mysql_connect("link", "user", "pw");           
    mysql_select_db("user", $connection); 

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['brukernavn']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passord']);


    // Check the users input against the DB.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM brukere WHERE brukernavn = '$username' AND passord = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Unable to verify user because " . mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($row['total'] == 1)

    {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "true";
        header("Location: insertlink");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "false";
        echo "<p>Login failed, username or password incorrect.</p>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I know you said you're new to PHP/MySQL, so I recommend starting off right and NOT using the mysql_* functions. Look at mysqli or PDO (the latter being my personal preference). We would also need to see your registration code. Are you encrypting passwords when you save them?

Comment: 1. `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. 2. You're storing clear-text passwords in your database, which is very bad.

Comment: @lxg - I wish I could give that about a 100 upvotes...

Comment: @rar Thanks! I'll check them out. Is this my registration code then?
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nyttbrukernavn']);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nyttpassord']);

 if(!isset($username) || trim($password) == '')
 {
    echo "Fyll ut de nødvendige feltene.";
 }
 else{
 $sql="INSERT INTO brukere (brukernavn, passord)
 VALUES ('$username', '$password')";

Comment: Yep, that's the insert statement. It looks like you're not encrypting the passwords (which you should be), so that doesn't answer why the login failed. Upon closer inspection, though, it looks like lxg pointed out the correct thing - there's no `$row['total']`, so it will automatically fail that conditional check.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `total` field in the array returned by `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

If you want to know the number of results, use the [`count`](http://php.net/count) function:

```
if(count($rows) === 1)
…
```

Btw, as already mentioned:

1. `mysql_*` is deprecated, use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo).
2. You're storing clear-text passwords in your database, which is very bad. Please read about hashing and salting stored passwords.

Comment: [php documentation on password encryption](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: @lxg Thank you so much, sir! I'm going to check out mysqli_ and PDO.

Comment: nice link @gloomy.penguin. Didn't know that PHP has a dedicated article about this.

Comment: @JonHåvardHalvorsen: You're welcome. You will find mysqli to be more similar to the deprecated mysql (meaning that it may be easier to update `mysql_*` code to `mysqli_*`), while PDO is more "object oriented". In any case, you should use prepared statements instead of manually escaping data input. (which at least you do, others don't even care about that. ;))